# Number of minimal primes for UFD

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, galois-representations, nonnoetherian

Let $R$ be a UFD which is NOT noetherian. It is well-known that $R$
is a Krull ring. Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ such that the height of $I$
is $d$ which is finite.

Question. Is the number of minimal primes of $I$ finite?
That is, are there only finitely many primes $P_i$ such that 
$P_i \supset I$ and that the height of $P_i$ is $d$?

---

For example, the polynomial ring $K[X_1,...,X_\infty]$ of infinitely
many variables over a field $K$ is UFD.

Also the power series ring $K[[X_1,...,X_\infty]]$ over a field $K$
of infinitely many variables is UFD.

What is the number of minimal primes of $I$ for these UFDs ?

Pierre Matsumi

Comment: I guess you have two questions: one is asking if the number of minimal primes over $I$ is finite, and the other asks if there are finitely many prime ideals of height $d$ containing $I$. I don't see why you think they are equivalent.